# Yii nested URL parameters

Tags: yii, url-routing

Can anyone point me in the right direction in order to write a URL rule in order to achieve the following:
Using the base controller I want to get to each of the parameters in this url:
DomainName/clientID/fileID

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Haven't tested it, but this should work:

```
'rules' => array(
  '<clientID:\d+>/<fileID:\d+>' => 'myBaseController/myAction',
)
```

Just make sure the one rule gets added before your Yii default URL rules.  FYI, the rule assumes that both client ID and file ID are integers.  If fileID contains letters, change it to fileID:\w+.

Answer (score 0):

```
$url = $this->createUrl('timeSheetDetaile/create',array('timesheetID'=>$timeSheedID,'dayID'=>1));
```

first param is the name of your controller and second  array is $_GET params ..
have fun.

Comment: But isn't that to create a URL to go to that action? I'm trying to figure out how to set the urlManager rules in the main config to allow for two nested parameters that direct to the defaultController without mentioning the controller name in the URL. Because people will be given these URL's from outside the system.

Comment: dont worry about URL will be build

Comment: the domain name wont be in URL .. you wnat your domain name before controller ??

Comment: Yeah, I'm aiming for http://domain/parameter/parameter[then standard post vars]. Without the controller name or action being in the URL